# Cucumber Serenity NoSuchMethodException cucumber.runtime.SerenityBackend(ResourceLoader, TypeRegistry)

Tags: cucumber, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I am trying to run a sample cucumber test with Serenity which works perfectly fine when run with Cucumber.
However, i get the below error though I made sure all the dependencies are added to maven pom file.

**Below are the versions of Serenity and Cucumber.**
serenity: 2.0.40
serenity-cucumber: 1.9.31
cucumber: 4.2.5

**Below is the Exception trace:**

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: cucumber.runtime.SerenityBackend.<init>(cucumber.runtime.io.ResourceLoader, io.cucumber.stepexpression.TypeRegistry)
    at cucumber.runtime.Reflections.newInstance(Reflections.java:54)
    at cucumber.runtime.Reflections.instantiateSubclasses(Reflections.java:36)
    at cucumber.runtime.BackendModuleBackendSupplier.loadBackends(BackendModuleBackendSupplier.java:52)
    at cucumber.runtime.BackendModuleBackendSupplier.get(BackendModuleBackendSupplier.java:39)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: cucumber.runtime.SerenityBackend.<init>(cucumber.runtime.io.ResourceLoader, io.cucumber.stepexpression.TypeRegistry)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
    at cucumber.runtime.Reflections.newInstance(Reflections.java:46)
    ... 29 more
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: As `serenity-cucumber` is using internal apis from `cucumber-jvm`. You should use the version as defined by `serenity-cucumber` and not add your own dependency on Cucumber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Cucumber 4, you need to use the serenity-cucumber4 library - see https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-cucumber4-starter.

Comment: https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-cucumber/blob/master/src/main/java/cucumber/runtime/SerenityBackend.java#L23 does not implement the Backend interface correctly. It was changed in v4.2.5. I considered it to be an internal API (it's not in the API package). See:

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/core/src/main/java/cucumber/runtime/Backend.java#L13